# Disable shipping in Magento to a specific country in all stores except one

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We would like to disable shipping to the UK from all of our store views except for the .co.uk store view...

I have created my own custom shipping module following the guides on http://techportal.inviqa.com/2011/06/09/creating-a-custom-magento-shipping-method/ and http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

As you can see, in both of the above links, there is an xml block that states whether or not to allow all countries, or specific countries

```
<sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
```

The description of the above block follows

```
sallowspecific  set to 1 to limit the countries the rate is applicable to
```

I could really use an example of what the config.xml should look like with sallowspecific set to 1

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These line of codes will only set the default value for your module if they are not set by the user after install

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <shippingName>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
```

When `sallowspecific` is set to 0 it will enable your country selector so you can select which country you want to ship to, to get a better understanding of how this work take a look at 'Flat Rate' and change the option for 'Ship to Applicable Countries' and take a look at what happen to 'Ship to Specific Countries'.

This is what the 1 and 0 set

```
 <select id="carriers_flatrate_sallowspecific" name="groups[flatrate][fields][sallowspecific][value]" class="shipping-applicable-country select">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">All Allowed Countries</option>
     <option value="1">Specific Countries</option>
 </select>
```

If `sallowspecific` was set to 1 then your default should look like

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <shippingName>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            <specificcountry>US,GB</specificcountry>
```

In your system.xml you need to have

```
   <sallowspecific translate="label">
        <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </sallowspecific>
    <specificcountry translate="label">
        <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>91</sort_order>
        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
    </specificcountry>
```

Then go to each store view and select the applicable countries.

Answer (score 4):

There is a configuration option that sets what countries you allow. By default, all countries are selected. You can modify this as low as the store view level to remove the UK store. You can find it here:

`System -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Countries Options -> Allow Countries`

If there are going to be multiple cases like this, I would suggest disabling UK and any other countries at a global level and then enabling the countries you want on a per store / store view level. This should help you manage most of your store views without having to update every single one by hand.

Comment: I am torn between which answer to accept, Jake gave me the answer I needed, and R.S. gave me the answer I wanted =P